# Drools compare if one list contains element from another list

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have got below structure in Java:

```
public class Request {
  List<Product> product;
  List<Account> accounts;
}

public class Product {
 String productIdOne;
 String productIdTwo;
 String productTax;
}  


public class Account {
  List<ProductRelationship> productsRelationship;
}
public class ProductRelationship {
  String productIdOne;
  String productIdTwo;
}
```

And the request is the fact object send to drools. I am wondering how I can check if there is at least one product that productTax is set to 'true' and there is a relationship between one account and one product. In other words, if there is a product with tax set to true and at least one account contains a relationship with this product (by productIdOne and productIdTwo) then the rule result should pass;

The main issue is that the list of the product relationship is inside the account list.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather straight-forward set of conditions, so it is possible to write a relatively simple rule to check them. I will consider each condition separately and then combine them into a final rule.

As you wrote:

> there is at least one product that productTax is set to 'true'

Now, as you mentioned, your rule inputs are the `Request` instance which contains two lists (products, accounts.) We'll start by declaring that:

```
rule "Account exists with taxed product"
when
  Request( $products: product != null, 
           $accounts: accounts != null )
```

Next, we want to find the taxed product. If we only wanted to prove the existence of the product, we could use an `exists( ... )` condition, which is extremely fast. However since we want to do further comparisons, we'll want to actuall find the product with this condition and save a reference to it.

```
$taxedProduct: Product( productTax == "true" ) from $products
```

I've assumed here that any value other than exactly "true" is indicative of an untaxed product. You should adjust as needed (and possibly consider changing this type to a boolean.)

The next condition is to find the account:

> there is a relationship between one account and [the taxed] product

First, we'll need to update our `$taxedProduct` declaration and get references to its ids:

```
$taxedProduct: Product( productTax == "true",
                        $id1: productIdOne,
                        $id2: productIdTwo ) from $products
```

Now we need to find an account with a matching relationship.

```
$account: Account( $relationships: productsRelationship != null ) from $accounts
exists( ProductRelationship( productIdOne == $id1,
                             productIdTwo == $id2 ) from $relationships )
```

Here, I used an `exists` condition for the relationship because we don't need to refer to the relationship itself ever again, just verify that the relationship exists. I did declare a variable `$account` to point to the account that has the product relationship.

Putting it all together, we have:

```
rule "Account exists with taxed product"
when
  Request( $products: product != null, 
           $accounts: accounts != null )
           
  $taxedProduct: Product( productTax == "true",
                          $id1: productIdOne,
                          $id2: productIdTwo ) from $products

  $account: Account( $relationships: productsRelationship != null ) from $accounts
  exists( ProductRelationship( productIdOne == $id1,
                               productIdTwo == $id2 ) from $relationships )
then
  // We have a taxed product $taxedProduct
  // and an associated account $account
end
```

When I first started with Drools I found it difficult to wrap my head around the way it treated objects in lists, which is why the ProductRelationship sub-list seems like a tricky issue on its face. What Drools is going to do is iterate through the $products list and find those Product instances that meet our criteria (namely, have `productTax == "true"`.) Once it has found these taxed products, it then similarly goes through the $accounts list and finds all Accounts that meet the criteria (which have a productsRelationship list.) Then for each of those accounts, it is going to test that there exists a relationship as we've defined.

This is a simplified explanation, of course, but it helps to form a mental model of roughly what Drools is doing here. In reality Drools is much more efficient than then roughly O(n^3) workflow I've just described.

An interesting thing you should keep in mind is that this rule is not going to "stop" as soon as it finds a match. If you have two taxed products that have a relationship to a single account, this rule will fire twice -- once for each taxed product. Or, alternatively, if you have one taxed product and two accounts that have a relationship to it, the rule will fire twice (once for each account.) Basically, the rule will fire once for each "match" it finds in the given request.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this following

```
 rule "sample"
  no-loop
   

      when
         request:Request(accountList: accounts)
         request1:Request(productList: product)
         Account(productsRelationshipList:ProductRelationship) from accountList
         Product(productId contains productsRelationshipList, productTax = true ) from  productList
      then
          System.out.println("Rule fired satisfied");
      end
```